Binding to parent control with context menu in UWP (WinUI 3)
I am trying to make a context fold out menu on a list box component, it has a simple but i can't manage to get the binding for command paramter to work.
Here is a simplified view of my user control XAML.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
    x:Class="SampleControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SampleUWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:inter="microsoft"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel}">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                <ListBox.ContextFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding Add}"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove" Command="{Binding Remove}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myList}"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </ListBox.ContextFlyout>
            </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

A simple representation of a ViewModel.
public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand Add {get;} // Ignored for now
    public ICommand Remove {get;} = new DelegatedCommand(OnRemove, CanRemove)
    
    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemSource {get;} = new [] {
        new Item { Id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Second" }
    }

    private bool CanRemove(object param)
    {
        // We want param to be the list item so we can get the Id
    }

    private OnRemove(object obj)
    {
        // Do some logic for removing
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

I have tried finding a solution on this on forums but nothing i tried has worked, the closest i have come is to get the MenuFlyoutItem with {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}} but i don't know a way to get my list box from here either.
I understand that the context menu it self is in a different visual tree just like in WPF but there i could get the source by using relative source and using find ancestor but in UWP i cannot seam to find a solution on how to bind my command parameter to the list item so i can send it as a paramter.
One note to mention is that there is no problem with the command, it resolves to the ViewModel without issues, but the command parameter i cannot figure out.

Is your project a UWP project? how do you use DelegatedCommand in UWP?

Assign an x:Name  to the UserControl and use that name in the ElementName binding, as follows: Command="{Binding Add, ElementName=Root, Mode=OneTime}

Maybe you could try the following code.
Xaml:

  <ListBox.ContextFlyout>
      <MenuFlyout>
          <!--<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding Add}"/>-->
          <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove" Command="{Binding Remove}" />
      </MenuFlyout>
  </ListBox.ContextFlyout>

ViewModel Code-behind:
  public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public ICommand Add { get; } // Ignored for now
      public ICommand Remove
      {
          get
          {
              return new CommadEventHandler<string>((s) => this.OnRemove(s));
          }

      }
      public IEnumerable<Item> ItemSource { get; } = new[] {
      new Item { Id = 1, Name = "First" },
      new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Second" }
      };

      private int _selectedIndx;

      public int SelectedIndx
      {
          get { return _selectedIndx; }
          set
          {
              _selectedIndx = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndx");
          }
      }
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
          {
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }


      private void OnRemove(object obj)
      {
          // Do some logic for removing
          if (SelectedIndx < 0 || SelectedIndx > ItemSource.Count())
          {
              return;
          }

          Item selectedItem = ItemSource.ElementAt(SelectedIndx);

          Debug.WriteLine(selectedItem.Name);

      }
  }

